# Structuring a VBA form to move excel rows around.

Tags: vba, forms, excel, form-submit

Apologies in advance, I don't have a specific code example to work on, this is more of a question about possible options to perform a task with a VBA form.

I have a data set that I need to run through an error-checking procedure. Part of this procedure is moving some rows of data from the original table to one of two other tables. I can find these rows by the invoice number column (one of 12ish columns on the data). The form I'm working on has a setup where the user inputs the invoice # into a text box and clicks a button to add it to a listbox. The problem comes with what to do next with the "finish/continue" button.

I can add the list box invoice numbers to an array just fine, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. A guy at my work suggested writing the array to a table and then using MATCH beside it to get the cell reference and potentially pull the row from that, but I can't get this to work properly; writing the array to a table is evading me, and then getting the cell values into another array just doesn't seem like it's going to work well, because even then you have to read the row, and then somehow select the row of the underlying table, and then cut the table row out... etc etc.

I though perhaps running a filter on the data's invoice column using the array would work, but I have no idea how to write that. This might make selecting the range easier (just .databodyrange? Might not work on only the filtered area...).

Anyways, do you have any ideas or know of an example for something similar?

Thanks :3

Comment: Does creating a completely new workbook containing your result table work for you?

Comment: Do you have any code so far?  If Yes you should include that in your question.

Comment: @Tehscript ideally not but what's your idea? 

Tim Williams, the only relevant code I still have is creating the array and dumping the list box into it, which has nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to look up values you can use [`Range.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839746.aspx), [`.VLookUp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff194701.aspx) and [`.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff835873.aspx), the difference is the return value. I dont know why he suggested writing it to an array but you can just use the value of the textbox. You can not look up multiple values at once. And before going on with it, i would check if a match exists.

To give you an example for all Methods:

```
Private Sub txtInvoice_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim txt As String: txt = txtInvoice.Text
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Result As Variant, ResultRng As Range, MReturn As Variant

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'.Match
If IsNumeric(txt) Then
    Result = Application.Match(CLng(txt), sht.Range("A:A"), 0)
Else
    Result = Application.Match(txt, sht.Range("A:A"), 0)
End If
If Not IsError(Result) Then
    MReturn = sht.Cells(Result, 3).Value
    MsgBox MReturn
Else
    MsgBox ("Not Found!")
    txtInvoice.SetFocus
    Cancel = True
End If

'OR

'.VLookUp
If IsNumeric(txt) Then
    Result = Application.VLookup(CLng(txt), sht.Range("A:C"), 3, False)
Else
    Result = Application.VLookup(txt, sht.Range("A:C"), 3, False)
End If
If Not IsError(Result) Then
    MReturn = Result
    MsgBox MReturn
Else
    MsgBox ("Not Found!")
    txtInvoice.SetFocus
    Cancel = True
End If

'OR

'.Find
Set ResultRng = sht.Range("A:A").Find(txt, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not ResultRng Is Nothing Then
    MReturn = sht.Cells(ResultRng.Row, 3).Value
    MsgBox MReturn
Else
    MsgBox ("Not Found!")
    txtInvoice.SetFocus
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

So in order to try it out yourself, you will need a `Textbox` called `txtInvoice` and a another object (like a button, you can set focus to). The Worksheet to Match is `Sheet1`. The value is looked up in Col `A` and the return value in Col `C`. If you tab out/switch focus to the other object by clicking it the sub will activate and try to match. If it cannot then it will give out a message and refocus the `Textbox`.

I would recommend using `.Find`, has the highest number of options and easiest to use. `VLookUp` and `Match` can have problems with numbers so thats why i convert them to real numbers, `.Find` doesnt have this issue.

Comment: Thanks @UGP, this is a great place to start. I already have the form set up plus a secondary form if there's no match (allows user to input the invoice info manually) but I was just missing this section of the code. The initial plan with the array was to allow the user to review the invoice numbers before hitting the continue button, but if that's not going to work the form will still be fine.